# Optimize a delete query

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I would like to know if there is any option to improve and optimize my query. I am importing schedule data for our staff and need to delete the old data, when it is existing for this agent and day. The reason is, that agents may don't exist for everyday (because they left the company) and it could be, that we upload a more updated report as we did before (recent schedule changes).

That's why I currently have this query:

```
DELETE FROM `agents` WHERE 
(`id` = 1 AND `date` => '01.01.2015 00:00:00' AND `date` <= '01.01.2015 23:59:59') OR 
(`id` = 2 AND `date` => '01.01.2015 00:00:00' AND `date` <= '01.01.2015 23:59:59') OR [...]
```

This combination is for each agent of the report and each day in the report. I uploaded one which created 5780 day/agent combinations. This query took on my (currently) small table about 5 minutes to be executed.

I am wondering if anyone has an idea how I could improve this thing.

Comment: composite index on id, date would make it snappy !

Comment: is this every time a full import of the new data ? if so you can truncate the table before you import the new.

Comment: I need to keep the old entries for agents who are not in the new version of the report. Because it can happen that they left the company and unfortunately we don't have them in a monthly report when they left during the month. In fact, I just want to delete the old entries for people who are in the new report. Other old data should keep untouched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is going to be rather difficult.  As written, it probably requires a full table scan.

One method would be to add an index on `agents(id, date)` and to do the deletes separately:

```
DELETE FROM `agents`
    WHERE (`id` = 1 AND date >= '2015-01-01' AND `date` < '2015-01-02');

DELETE FROM `agents`
    WHERE (`id` = 2 AND date >= '2015-01-01' AND `date` < '2015-01-02')
```

Assuming the dates are all the same, you can write the `where` clause as:

```
DELETE FROM `agents`
    WHERE `id` IN (1, 2, 3, . . . ) AND
           `date` >= '2015-01-01' AND `date` < '2015-01-02';
```

Depending on the distribution of the data (number of dates per id in the range) weight, either the above index or one on `agents(date, id)` would be best.

Comment: I like your 2nd idea. I tried to first one on a another point of the project and noticed that it take ages to perform each query separately. That's why I joined them together to one big `DELETE`

Comment: @MichaelWalter . . . An appropriate index would speed the individual deletes.  If you have a lot, though, you are incurring the overhead of the transactions for each one.  You can get around that by wrapping them in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a table like this:

```
create table t123
(   id int not null,
    date datetime not null,
    myThing varchar(10) not null 
);
```

And you later added an index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE t123 ADD INDEX (id,date);   -- add an index after the fact
```

Then a delete from like yours on table `t123` would perform as fast as I could imagine. **However** it would need to maintain the index along the way, and it is baggage to consider.

All index changes need to be carefully weighed. The benefit of quicker access, at the expense of slowing down inserts/updates/deletes.

Manual pages of [Fast Engine Creation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-create-index-examples.html) and [Alter Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: btw, I totally missed the fact that you had multiple delete stmts going. Sorry about that